# document.write javascript from mysql database and treating escapes

Tags: javascript, php

I have some javascript code that I want to add to the page on load. This code has been saved to a **mysql** database 'as is'.

e.g. Google Adsense code or other Javascript snippets taken directly from the provider.

This is the code that I was using, but it is obviously replacing the wrong characters and not escaping when it should.

```
document.write("<?php echo str_replace('"',"'", preg_replace('#<\/script>#', '<\\/script>', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', wordpressPlugin_get_option('source', 'field'))))); ?>");
```

How can I change the way I am parsing this retrieved string from the **database** so that I can add it to the page without the wrong characters being escaped?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why can't you just use php echo directly, without invoking document.write as well? I would have thought you can just render it directly in that case, without using any replacement

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var code = "<code>&lt;?php {YOUR PHP CODE HERE} ?&gt;</code>";
    document.write(code);
</script>
```